# NullPointerException when i want to GET my data from my model class

Tags: java, android

In my Application in android i want to GET data from my web service to my recycle view, instead i got my data i got an error, here is my code

```
public class UserMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_menu);

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://172.31.32.17:9290/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    afs = retrofit.create(AdminFullService.class);

    responseLoginHome = (ResponseLoginHome) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");

    initViews();

    getCustomer = new getCustomer();

  }

  private void initViews() {
    recyclerViewCustomer = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_user_menu);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerViewCustomer.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerViewCustomer.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapterCustomer = new DataAdapterCustomer(this, getCustomerList);
    loadData();
  }

  private void loadData() {

    Call<ResponseCustomerData> callCustomer = afs.customerDataView("bearer " + responseLoginHome.getData().getAuth_token());
    callCustomer.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseCustomerData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseCustomerData> call, Response<ResponseCustomerData> response) {
            ResponseCustomerData responseCustomerData = response.body();
            getCustomerList.clear();
            getCustomerList.addAll(responseCustomerData.getData()); //this is where i got error in my logcat
            recyclerViewCustomer.setAdapter(adapterCustomer);
            adapterCustomer.notifyDataSetChanged();
            getCustomer.getTanggalLahir().substring(0,10);
            Toast.makeText(UserMenu.this, getCustomer.getTanggalLahir(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseCustomerData> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
  }
}
```

and i have got this error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.example.ipul.aprovementfullservice.Model.ResponseCustomerData.getData()' on a null object reference
>
> at com.example.ipul.aprovementfullservice.UI.UserMenu$1.onResponse(UserMenu.java:77)

when i use my debug mode the responseCustomerData is null, and then i got confused why i got error like this, i create my model response just like my web service ask
sorry for bad grammar, English is not my native language
So i hope you all hand me your help, thank you

EDIT this is my list getCustomer

```
public class getCustomer{
  public String getNoHP() {
    return noHP;
  }

  public void setNoHP(String noHP) {
    this.noHP = noHP;
  }

  public String getRegistrationDate() {
    return registrationDate;
  }

  public void setRegistrationDate(String registrationDate) {
    this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
  }

  public String getNama() {
    return nama;
  }

  public void setNama(String nama) {
    this.nama = nama;
  }

  public String getNoID() {
    return noID;
  }

  public void setNoID(String noID) {
    this.noID = noID;
  }

  public String getJenisID() {
    return jenisID;
  }

  public void setJenisID(String jenisID) {
    this.jenisID = jenisID;
  }

  public String getTanggalLahir() {
    return tanggalLahir;
  }

  public void setTanggalLahir(String tanggalLahir) {
    this.tanggalLahir = tanggalLahir;
  }

  public String getJenisKelamin() {
    return jenisKelamin;
  }

  public void setJenisKelamin(String jenisKelamin) {
    this.jenisKelamin = jenisKelamin;
  }

  public String getNamaIbuKandung() {
    return namaIbuKandung;
  }

  public void setNamaIbuKandung(String namaIbuKandung) {
    this.namaIbuKandung = namaIbuKandung;
  }

  public String getAlamat() {
    return alamat;
  }

  public void setAlamat(String alamat) {
    this.alamat = alamat;
  }

  public String getProvinsi() {
    return provinsi;
  }

  public void setProvinsi(String provinsi) {
    this.provinsi = provinsi;
  }

  public String getKota() {
    return kota;
  }

  public void setKota(String kota) {
    this.kota = kota;
  }

  public String getKecamatan() {
    return kecamatan;
  }

  public void setKecamatan(String kecamatan) {
    this.kecamatan = kecamatan;
  }

  public String getKelurahan() {
    return kelurahan;
  }

  public void setKelurahan(String kelurahan) {
    this.kelurahan = kelurahan;
  }

  public String getKodepos() {
    return kodepos;
  }

  public void setKodepos(String kodepos) {
    this.kodepos = kodepos;
  }

  public String getAlamatDomosili() {
    return alamatDomosili;
  }

  public void setAlamatDomosili(String alamatDomosili) {
    this.alamatDomosili = alamatDomosili;
  }

  public String getProvinsiDomisili() {
    return provinsiDomisili;
  }

  public void setProvinsiDomisili(String provinsiDomisili) {
    this.provinsiDomisili = provinsiDomisili;
  }

  public String getKotaDomisili() {
    return kotaDomisili;
  }

  public void setKotaDomisili(String kotaDomisili) {
    this.kotaDomisili = kotaDomisili;
  }

  public String getKecamatanDomisili() {
    return kecamatanDomisili;
  }

  public void setKecamatanDomisili(String kecamatanDomisili) {
    this.kecamatanDomisili = kecamatanDomisili;
  }

  public String getKelurahanDomisili() {
    return kelurahanDomisili;
  }

  public void setKelurahanDomisili(String kelurahanDomisili) {
    this.kelurahanDomisili = kelurahanDomisili;
  }

  public String getKodeposDomisili() {
    return kodeposDomisili;
  }

  public void setKodeposDomisili(String kodeposDomisili) {
    this.kodeposDomisili = kodeposDomisili;
  }

  public String getFotoID() {
    return fotoID;
  }

  public void setFotoID(String fotoID) {
    this.fotoID = fotoID;
  }

  public String getRegisterStatus() {
    return registerStatus;
  }

  public void setRegisterStatus(String registerStatus) {
    this.registerStatus = registerStatus;
  }

  public String getKeterangan() {
    return keterangan;
  }

  public void setKeterangan(String keterangan) {
    this.keterangan = keterangan;
  }

  public String getFotoTandaTangan() {
    return fotoTandaTangan;
  }

  public void setFotoTandaTangan(String fotoTandaTangan) {
    this.fotoTandaTangan = fotoTandaTangan;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }
}
```

and this my model ResponseCustomerData

```
public class ResponseCustomerData{
  public String getTag() {
    return tag;
  }

  public void setTag(String tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
  }

  public String getSuccess() {
    return success;
  }

  public void setSuccess(String success) {
    this.success = success;
  }

  public String getError() {
    return error;
  }

  public void setError(String error) {
    this.error = error;
  }

  public List<getCustomer> getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(List<getCustomer> data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

Comment: check if you have initialized getCustomerList if its and array list.

Comment: simply your response doesn't contain the data type assigned in getData() method

Comment: where have you initialized getCustomerList, and you are getting null in this part responseCustomerData.getData(), that means you have to check the api part, you are using Retrofit so check there

Comment: post your response and your getData() method

Comment: i already initialized my getCustomerList as array list like this private List<getCustomer> getCustomerList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: so must check my response and my model so it same like in my web service?

Comment: Post your sample response `JSON`

Comment: @Ipul you can use getCustomerList = new ArrayList<>(); inside your response in loadData() method.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, you have to check if your response is null or not.

```
Call<ResponseCustomerData> callCustomer = afs.customerDataView("bearer " + responseLoginHome.getData().getAuth_token());
    callCustomer.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseCustomerData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseCustomerData> call, Response<ResponseCustomerData> response) {
            ResponseCustomerData responseCustomerData = response.body();
            getCustomerList.clear();
            if(responseCustomerData!=null){ // check data retrive or not                    
                if(responseCustomerData.getData()!=null){
                    getCustomerList.addAll(responseCustomerData.getData());
                    recyclerViewCustomer.setAdapter(adapterCustomer);
                    adapterCustomer.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    getCustomer.getTanggalLahir().substring(0,10);
                    Toast.makeText(UserMenu.this, getCustomer.getTanggalLahir(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("Error", responseCustomerData.getError());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseCustomerData> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```